# Disable Ajax Add to Cart on product page in Magento

Tags: ajax, magento, shopping-cart

In our webshop we use a ajax add to cart, so the page doesn't have to reload. But when the order is bigger then the stock. The ajax keeps loading and doesn't show a message the order isn't available.

The console error is: 503 (Service Unavailable)

Is their a way to fix this or to disable ajax add to cart only on the product page but it keeps working on other pages!

Erro log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:81:"De gevraagde hoeveelheid voor "Restorative Hair Mask 250 ml" is niet beschikbaar.";i:1;s:1539:"#0 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(284): Mage::throwException('De gevraagde ho...')
#1 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(154): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct('53', Array)
#2 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/local/Cmsmart/AjaxCart/controllers/IndexController.php(67): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->tryaddAction(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), Array)
#3 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Cmsmart_AjaxCart_IndexController->indexAction()
#4 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#5 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/community/ArtsOnIT/OfflineMaintenance/Controller/Router/Standard.php(46): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#6 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): ArtsOnIT_OfflineMaintenance_Controller_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /home/users/beaxmftp/beautyballoon.nl/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}";s:3:"url";s:98:"/ajaxcart/index/index/?form_key=hGxTgs9rzs7WqBfZ&product=53&related_product=&qty=5&_=1446135436562";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"nl";}
```

Comment: It's worth checking your server error logs to see if there is any additional information regarding the error. Are you using an extension for AJAX functionality?

Comment: I have edited the question with the log. The ajax extension is ajax cart by csmmart

Comment: Firstly, I'd suggest reaching out to the developers.  Secondly, take a look at the indexAction of the IndexController for the AjaxCart plugin and see where it is throwing this exception, and handle it in a nicer way :)